# Precedent for compiling C++ to C# via C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

We've got a 1.2M-line legacy Visual C++ 6 code base and are considering different ways to modernize it. One idea is to alter this code to get it to compile to CIL as C++/CLI code and then use a tool like Reflector to decompile it back to C# and then maintain that code base going forwards.

Has anyone done anything like this before? Does it sound feasible?

Comment: Compilation, either to machine code or to some intermediate form, typically loses a *lot* of information; the generated code works, but it won't be maintainable.  You can't unscramble an egg.

Answer (score 3):

No direct experience of CLI or Reflector, but I'd guess that what you'd come up with might end up looking like pretty ugly C#.

Why not try converting a small number of representative files to see what happens?

My hunch is it'd be better and probably easier to bring the code up to VS10 keeping it as C++.

Comment: As 5+ year developer of C++/CLI, avoid it at all costs.  You're not going to be able to get usable C# code through the reflector I imagine, I don't think that works.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply pass `/clr`, you'll end up with use of C++ interop everywhere library functions are used.  Reflector won't know what to do with this.  There's no shortcut for translating use of C++ Standard Library to .NET libraries, there's no 1:1 correlation and architectural design tends to be quite different also.

For functions that perform pure computation, you might get something ugly but working.